# Swift 4 SegmenterControl with TableView

Tags: swift, tableview, customization, uisegmentedcontrol

I build a social app, now I want to make some good appearance. I want to change tabs Contacts / Rooms from segmentedCntrol. How can I do that with correct form? I have two ways...Clear contacts table view and fill it with Rooms data. Or hide view with a table view and display another view with new tableView.

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: You can use one tableview with two prototype cells.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR just clean tableView when index changed?

Comment: Yes. In cellForRow method check segmentcontrol index and use appropriate prototype cell

Comment: @RajeshKumarR ok thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create 2 tableViewCells and switch between them in `cellForRowAt` according to selected segment

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if  mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:CellIdentifier1) as!  Cell1

       // setup here

   }
   else{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:CellIdentifier2) as!  Cell2

        // setup here
   }
}
```